# Find the arc length of the following curve on the given interval by integrating with respect to x. y=x^3/3 + 1/4x [1,5]

Tags: calculus

Find the arc length of the following curve on the given interval by integrating with respect to x. $ y \ = \ \frac{x^3}{3} \  + \ \frac{1}{4x} \ $ , [1,5]

I know you set it up as $$\int_1^5\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \ \ dx \ \ . $$ But I'm not sure how to solve this integral.

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Since $ \ y' \ = \ x^2 \ - \ \frac{1}{4x^2} \ $ , something rather nice happens with $ ( 1 \ + \ [y']^2 ) \ $ .  (This is a **very** standard arclength problem...)

Comment: I edited in the differential $ \ dx \ $ on the definite integral -- without that, I imagine it _would_ look impossible to compute.